# Highstock: left-most column gets truncated depending on chosen end date

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highstock (version 2.1.8) to draw a column chart that has date-range-selection values of 7 days, 14 days, 6 weeks, 12 weeks, 6 months, and 12 months.  I'm well aware that data values have to be supplied for the complete date-range corresponding to any of those selections.  So, if the 6 week or 12 week range is selected, the date range of the data should, evidently, end on the last day of the week (I've configured weeks to begin on Sunday, so the last data point should fall on a Saturday).  Naturally, I only have real data through today, so I have to generate bogus data 3 days into the future if today happens to be a Wednesday.  But if the user selects the 7-day or 14-day range, then I want the last data point to fall on today's date.  The problem is that I obviously can't have it both ways.  So if my last data point falls on a Saturday that's 3 days in the future, the 7-day and 14-day views show data points for those future days -- not good.   But if my last data point is set to today (Wednesday), the weekly views get messed up, i.e. a partially truncated pair of columns appears on the left end of the chart.

Note that this problem only happens with column charts; it doesn't happen with line charts.  This is a bummer because I'd like to combine a column chart and line chart on the same graph.

This definitely seems like a bug. I checked if Highstock version 2.1.9 has the same issue, and it does.  I don't want to have to supply separate arrays of data points for daily views, weekly views, and monthly views.  Presumably, the monthly views will expect the last data point to fall on the last day of the month.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markshyn/pswoLmj7/5/) to illustrate the problem:

```
(There's too much code to show here, so please refer to the js fiddle).
```

Be sure and make a one-line edit to the Javascript code in the js fiddle:  search for the comment "modify this line" and subtract or add x days from today's date so as to make tmpDate fall on some day of the week other than Saturday.  Then look at the 6 week view, and you'll see the partially truncated (one of the two columns is missing) column pair on the left side of the chart.

Comment: If you set weekly point grouping and range will be of e.g. 6 weeks, but last week is not full, then visible are will contain part of (equal to number of days that last week lacks to be a full week) an older week. You could set range dynamically to compensate for week not being a full one through adjusting rangeSelector's button options. Do I understand your complex question correctly?

Comment: Kacper, thanks for your response.  Keep in mind that the problem described in the original post occurs with column charts but not with line charts, so I see this as inconsistent behavior.  Besides, I really think Highstock should be able to handle being given an array of data points with an arbitrary start and end date without displaying a (horizontally) truncated group of columns.   This just shouldn't happen.   Yes, I think the approach you've suggested can probably be used to correct the current behavior, but it really shouldn't be necessary.  Your help is nonetheless appreciated.

Comment: If you think that this is a bug, then you could report it on [Highcharts' github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues). If you think this is more like a suggestion and possible future improvement then you could start an suggestion on [userVoice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api) or vote for a one already suggested.